# How to implement arraylist into the ListView?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm just getting started with JavaFX which i find pretty cool , so i m trying to implement the arraylist of an ToDListItem class into the listView of my FXML file

i've tried to add items in my arraylist which is todoitems , then set it all into the listView which has an id 'ToDoList' in my FXML file but it seems nothing happpend when the UI display

```java
package sample;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import sample.ToDoList.ToDoItem;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Controller {
    private List<ToDoItem> todoitems;

    @FXML
    private ListView ToDoList ;

    public void intialize(){
        ToDoItem item1= new ToDoItem("Going to Sea","Going to Sea with thamer and kais",
                LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JUNE,16));
        ToDoItem item2= new ToDoItem("JavaFx","Getting ready for real programming real world stuff",
                LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JULY,14));
        ToDoItem item3= new ToDoItem("Sleep & Chill","Going to Watch Youtube Later & Chill",
                LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY,13));

        todoitems= new ArrayList<>();

        todoitems.add(item1);
        todoitems.add(item2);
        todoitems.add(item3);

        ToDoList.getItems().setAll(todoitems);
        ToDoList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    }
}
```

FXML file.

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<BorderPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <left>
      <ListView fx:id="ToDoList">
      </ListView>
  </left>
</BorderPane>
```

i didn't get any result when the UI displayed

Comment: Does `ToDoItem` override the `toString()` method, by chance? **Unrelated:** You should also be declaring the type for your `ListView`: `ListView<ToDoItem> lvToDoList;`

Comment: i've overrided it

Comment: Does the `ListView` show in the scene at all? If not, then the problem is with how you're loading the FXML file, not the code you've posted. It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: listView shows correctly but the content doesn't

Comment: You need to post your [mcve]. The problem is not in the code you've shown so far.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method should be named **initialize** but not **int**ialize. I would rather use [javafx.fxml.Initializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) to avoid misspelling issue.

[This is not the recommended approach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html):

```java
List<T> content = ...
getItems().setAll(content);
```

The issue with the approach shown above is that the content list is being copied into the items list.

Use:

```java
ObservableList<T> content = ...
listView.setItems(content);
```

```java
public class Controller {
    private final List<ToDoItem> todoItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private ListView ToDoList ;

    public void initialize() {
        ToDoList.setItems(todoItems);
        ToDoList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        populate();
    }

    private void populate () {
        todoItems.add(new ToDoItem("Going to Sea","Going to Sea with thamer and kais",
                LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JUNE,16)));
        todoItems.add(new ToDoItem("JavaFx","Getting ready for real programming real world stuff",
                LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JULY,14)));
        todoItems.add(new ToDoItem("Sleep & Chill","Going to Watch Youtube Later & Chill",
                LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY,13)));
    }
}
```

Make sure that the method *ToDoItem.toString* is overridden properly.

Comment: no: __never-ever__ override toString for application reasons (what would you do if you re-use the same object in different contexts with different visualization requirements?) Instead, use a custom cell.

Comment: I agree with @kleopatra. Real world applications shouldn't use toString as a part of business logic. The only reason to do it I guess is output debugging trace/logging.